# Codeigniter Login Script

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, system

I have a question regarding my codeigniter login script. It's not very complex but it works great. My question is, when a user is logged they get redirected to another part of my website, which is what I want but if that user loggs out, they or (anyone for that matter) still has access to the logged in URL. How do I make it so the URL is private?

For example, anyone has access to the below URL. How do I make sure the URL is private?
mywebsite.com/_states/site/members_area

Thanks Everyone

Site Controller

```
function validate_credentials()
{
  $this->load->model('model_data');
  $query = $this->model_data->validate_users();
   if($query){
      $data = array(
         'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
         'email' => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
         'is_logged_in' => TRUE
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata($data);

       redirect('site/members_area',$data);
   } else {
      $this->login();
   }

}
```

Model_data extends CI_Model

```
function validate_users()
{
  $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
  $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
  $query = $this->db->get('members');

  if ($query->num_rows == 0){
   }

  if ($query->num_rows == 1){
      return true;
   } 
}
```

members_area URL

```
<?php

echo 'Welcome!'.'<br>';

$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id').'<br>';
$whatever = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in').'<br>';
$email = $this->session->userdata('email').'<br>';
$username = $this->session->userdata('username').'<br>';

echo 'This is the session ID = '."$session_id".'<br>';
echo 'This is the boolean, 1 means true = User Logged In = '."$whatever".'<br>';
echo 'This is the user "foo" email = '."$email".'<br>';
echo 'This is the user username = '."$username".'<br>';
echo anchor('site/logout', 'Logout!');


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the session variable is set:

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
    // The user has logged in
}
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake on my part. Thank you. Just a quick side question. The $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') <--- I used this syntax within my view. Was this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: That's how I do it at least.

Comment: Ok thanks, I actually tried it in my Site Controller and it works that way as well. Thanks again!